# Enqueue script on logon failure

Tags: login

I have been playing arround for a day and didn't manage to achieve what I want. Is it possible to enqueue a script if user fails (username or password) to login? I checked and played arround with wp_login_failed but no luck so far!

I want to use this function in a popup login form. After login (success or failure) the page refreshes so I want to force pop up show automatically after a failure (user should not manually click the login button again) by adding javascript ( $('#login-dialog').show(); )

Answer (score 0):

I worked out a way to conditionally *print* a script to the head of the page, but not to actually enqueue it.

The code depends on the presence of the `wp_shake_js` callback that is [conditionally added to the login page on login failure](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-login.php#L56). If that hook is present, the assumption is that the login failed.

Unfortunately, that callback is hooked to [`login_head` which executes *after* `login_enqueue_scripts`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-login.php#L89) so you need to print the script, rather than enqueue it.

```
add_action(
  'login_head',
  function() {
    if (has_action('login_head','wp_shake_js')) {
      echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("howdy");</script>';
    }
  },
  13
);
```

I can't help but think there is a better way, but I can't find it (and I am running out of time for WPSE this morning :) ).

Comment: Thanks for the reply dum, printing the script would work for me too but I need to print it ONLY if the logon fail. :)

Comment: This should print for any login failure and not otherwise. Have you tested? Under what conditions does it behave incorrectly?

Comment: I want to use it in a popup login form. After login (success or failure) the page refreshes so I want to force pop up show  automatically after a failure (user should not manually click the login button again) by adding javascript ( $('#login-dialog').show();

Comment: This sounds like there is a fair bit of information missing from the question. Please fill in the missing details.